# Hooks for mouse - limitations and performance

Tags: c++, performance, winapi, hook

I have some question about WH_MOUSE. From what I've read, by putting the hook into a DLL it injects processes. Does it mean that capturing the mouse will work on my desktop, menu start etc. too? And what about title bar of applications? I've seen some posts over the Internet with such problems, but don't know if they failed with something or there's some kind of limitation (or another approach).

I also have a question about performance between WH_MOUSE and WH_MOUSE_LL. I found somewhere that the WM_MOUSE is faster than WH_MOUSE_LL, but is it really noticeable? If so in what situations it can slow system that much that we can notice that? If I want to record only clicks of the mouse and keyboard would WH_MOUSE_LL be efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are all the differences between WH_MOUSE and WH_MOUSE_LL hooks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872677/what-are-all-the-differences-between-wh-mouse-and-wh-mouse-ll-hooks)

Comment: if I understood correctly, low level things works in the way that it doesn't matter where we click, it always capture it. But what about not low level? The topic doesn't answer me that I have only guesswork. And the second paragraph of my topic? There's nothing about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Both hooks get you mouse input anywhere on the screen (other than cases listed below), they are essentially the same from this high-level functional point of view.
- Both are subject to UIPI: neither hook will get you mouse input when the mouse is over an elevated process.
- Low-level hooks don't require a DLL, so can be used by C#. The other type requires a separate DLL written in unmanaged code (C/C++).
- If running on a 64-bit machine, where you can have a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit processes running, a low-level hook will receive events from both types of processes, but the other type of hook will only see events from processes of the same 'bitness' as itself (this limitation derives from the use of a hook DLL; a 32-bit hook DLL can only hook into 32-bit processes, and similarly for 64-bit.) So if you care about this case, with a LL hook you need just one process, whereas with the other type of hook, you need two cooperating processes, one for 32 and one for 64.
- LL hook requires a message loop to be running.
- LL hooks are simpler to write, since the callback happens in your own process, so you can access your own global variables and so on. With the other type of hook, the callback happens in another process, so you have to do extra work to communicate the information back to your main process. (In both cases, you should keep the code in your callback minimal; just do basic filtering and checking, do any significant work from your mainline code, not the callback.)
- LL hooks are 'slower' because the input notification is marshaled to your process, processed there, and then the context switches back to the original process again. With the other type of hook, there's no context switch. This may or may not be noticeable to a user, however, and may depend on what you are doing in the callback, how your are handing the information, how long the hook is installed for, and other factors.

The issue with the title bar seems to be addressed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940156/setwindowshookex-with-wh-mouse-not-capturing-mouse-moves-over-htcaption-area); summary is that you get *WM_NCMOUSEMOVE* messages over the titlebar (and other non-client areas), WM_MOUSEMOVE elsewhere, so you have to check for *both*.

My 2c: if you are writing a simple utility or coding for fun, go with _LL; it's considerably easier and handles most of the trickier cases for you; you don't have to worry about 64/32bit issues or communicating between processes, so you get up and running sooner. When you've got your app logic working, you can convert the code to the other type of hook later if needed. On the other hand, if you want a more 'professional' app that is a 'good citizen' and minimizes its impact on other apps, then the other type of hook may be more appropriate; but as with all things perf releated, measure first, don't assume, so even then perhaps best to start of with a _LL hook anyway.